# How to prevent deletion from happening using triggers?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to create a trigger that would PREVENT any deletion on a given table if the day is either sunday or sat AND the time is between 14:00 and 16:00

Currently time is not a big deal, just how can I make the trigger stop the deletion action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_timedelete
   BEFORE DELETE
   ON test

    WHEN (TimeLogicEvaluatesToTrue)
 BEGIN
     raise_application_error (-20100, 'You can not delete at this time');
  END;
```

The raising of the error will implicitly rollback the transaction and stop the delete.

Comment: To evaluate the day of the week one might use this: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php